# "ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword”

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting "ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword” error for following query:

```
insert into candidate_address_t ('ADDRESS_LINE1','ADDRESS_LINE2','CITY','ADDRESS_ID','ZIP','CREATED_BY','MODIFIED_BY','CREATED_DATE','MODIFIED_DATE','ACTIVE_INACTIVE_FLG','ADDRESS_TYPE_ID','CANDIDATE_ID','STATE_ID','GOOGLE_MAP_LINK','SOURCE_TYPE_ID','COUNTRY_TYPE_ID')
values ('test',null,'test','0000','H3X 2P3','9304','9304', sysdate,sysdate,1,'0000','0000','000',null,1,1);
```

Comment: Remove single quotes from list of database table columns.

Comment: Yes, single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes for identifiers. Or skip quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into candidate_address_t (ADDRESS_LINE1
                                ,ADDRESS_LINE2
                                ,CITY
                                ,ADDRESS_ID
                                ,ZIP
                                ,CREATED_BY
                                ,MODIFIED_BY
                                ,CREATED_DATE
                                ,MODIFIED_DATE
                                ,ACTIVE_INACTIVE_FLG
                                ,ADDRESS_TYPE_ID
                                ,CANDIDATE_ID
                                ,STATE_ID
                                ,GOOGLE_MAP_LINK
                                ,SOURCE_TYPE_ID
                                ,COUNTRY_TYPE_ID)
values ('test'
       ,null
       ,'test'
       ,'0000'
       ,'H3X 2P3'
       ,'9304'
       ,'9304'
       ,sysdate
       ,sysdate
       ,1
       ,'0000'
       ,'0000'
       ,'000'
       ,null
       ,1
       ,1);
```

Also, instead of explicitly inserting `null` into a column, simply omit the column from the list.
Also, you don't need the columns list if you supply a value for every column in the values list.